# JQuery jsonp callback not firing when server responds with 200

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

I'm trying to access a public api using jquerys ajax function. I can see the request responds with HTTP code 200 and has data with developer tools but the success method doesn't fire, there error is

**Error: mycallback was not called**

```
$.ajax({
        url: rootUrl + endpoints[0],
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            all: false,
            date: getIsoDate(),
            city_id: 3
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');

            console.log(data);



        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
    });

function mycallback(data) {
    alert("jsonpCallback");
}
```

And if i try just setting the data type to json it get the cross site domain origin header not present.

Comment: And are you sure the API supports JSONP at all ?

Comment: You could try `window.mycallback = function(data) { ... ` as it should be global

Comment: it responds with json for sure, i can just paste the request url in the browser and get a json response

Comment: But JSON isn't JSONP, it's not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to define both callback and success. Try removing the callback as Jquery will handle that for you in a better way. You can do processing in success block.